# Passing request with ssl certificate with other machine

Tags: nginx, ssl, pki

Im newbie with this and I need suggestion about my configuration. so, I had this schema

```
  machine A <---------> machine B <----------> machine c
192.xxx.xx.x           10.184.x.x             10.148.x.x
                      centos, nginx        centos,nginx,nodejs
```

**note**
machine A just know IP machine B, as well as machine C that just know IP B. B are trying to passing the request of both machine A and C.

Machine A is my partner IP, both machine B and C are my IP. on side A, they gives me a certificate (root, subca and child cert) to bind with every request that directed to A. Whats best to use on machine B to passing every request with ssl bind on each request to be passing to the machine A?

I already trying to use nginx to proxy_pass but its just not working, with iptables forwarding also not give anything.

Comment: Honestly, I could not understand what you're trying to achieve. If machine A has a valid public SSL certificate - then what is the problem accessing it from anywhere, including machines B and C? Simply add the domain name of machine A into `/etc/hosts` file on machines B and C.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. As far as I know, the partner want to attach this certificate when I hit their url. So it's authenticate and accept to them. Im trying to attach it on Nodejs at C, but still doesn't look works to reach out them. Until now I still figure it out how to attach the ssl every time we hit the url.

Comment: You should clarify whether this SSL certicifate is server-side or client-side - they are slightly different and, as the name suggests, the former lives on the server (machine A) while the latter lives on the client (both machines B and C).

Comment: Oh you're right, this is client side certificate that every request must authenticate with partner. Machine A create the SSL and want to attach the ssl (whether is B or C). Until now when the C trying to hit through B its always stuck on (IP B its not in the cert list), whereas B its just a medium to redirect the request to machine A.

Comment: Client-side certificates do not contain an IP address - usually the server only checks that the client-side certificate has not expired, that it is signed by a CA that is trusted by the server, and eventually that the email in the certificate is among the recognized emails - but that last check is often left to your server-side scripts/application. You can read more on https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344, https://www.scriptjunkie.us/2013/11/adding-easy-ssl-client-authentication-to-any-webapp/, https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm

Comment: its pretty helping me thanks @IVOGELOV